# Let $E_1$ be a measurable set and $E_2$ be any bounded set, how to prove $m^*(E_1\cup E_2)+m^*(E_1\cap E_2) = m(E_1)+m^*(E_2)$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E_1$ be a measurable set and $E_2$ be any bounded set. How to prove
$$m^*(E_1\cup E_2)+m^*(E_1\cap E_2) = m(E_1)+m^*(E_2)?$$
the fact that the outer measure does not have finite additivity caused me a lot of trouble.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to prove this proposition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $m^* E_1$ is infinite **iff**  $m^*(E_1 \cup E_2) $ is infinite, so the equation holds vacuously in this case.

So we can presume that $E_1$ has finite measure.

For any set $A$ we have $m^*A = m^*(A\cap E_1) + m^*(A \setminus E_1)$.

With $A=E_2$ we get $m^* E_2 = m^*(E_1 \cap E_2) + m^*(E_2 \setminus E_1)$.

With $A=E_1 \cup E_2$ we get $m^*(E_1 \cup E_2) = m E_1 + m^*(E_2 \setminus E_1)$.

Adding gives the desired result.

Boundedness is used to ensure that subtraction is valid.

Comment: sorry, last line is unclear:  used where?

Comment: To ensure that $m^*(E_2 \setminus E_1)$ is finite.

Comment: i see... but you don't need that, do you?

Comment: I need it. I do. You need to subtract it from both sides to finish.

Comment: Thanks for your help.but I don't understand why for any set $A$, we have $$m^∗(A)=m^∗(A∩E1)+m^∗(A∖E1)$$.

Comment: That is the definition of measurable.

Comment: ok,I think i miss the Carath´eodory criterion.thank you so much again!

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$m^{*}(E_1\cup E_2) + m^{*}(E_1\cap E_2) = (m(E_1) + m^{*}(E_2\backslash E_1)) + m^{*}(E_1\cap E_2))= 
\\=m(E_1) + (m^{*}(E_2\backslash E_1) + m^{*}(E_1\cap E_2))= m(E_1)+ m^{*}(E_2) $$

Comment: This is nicer. ${}{}$

Comment: thanks for your help!